# Why Dialer shows contact name and image, when contact is not in my address book?

Tags: contacts, phone-app, google

Very often, when some unknown company is calling me, in couple of seconds I see its name and logo on standard Dialer's screen. Where does it take them, if I don't have this contact in my address book, nor do I have it in contacts in any social network, like FB, LinkedIn, etc? Does it search Google right at the moment of the call and shows me the result?

Comment: I already heard about services that search the number when you receive a call from someone not in your contact list but I can't remember the name right now. Anyway it would be better if you say what's your phone and rom (stock / custom) if you didn't install any app it probably comes with that.

Comment: @Crayon I just have stock KitKat and stock dialer app. See the answer below. Strange that I couldn't find it by googling, because it is described in many articles, as Izzy noted below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't explicitely mention it, but from the context I assume you're using a device with Android 4.4 (Kitkat). With that, Google "pimped" the dialer. *PhoneArena* writes on this in an article called [Google makes the Dialer awesome again: this is why you want Android 4.4 KitKat](http://www.phonearena.com/news/Google-makes-the-Dialer-awesome-again-this-is-why-you-want-Android-4.4-KitKat_id49430):

> I think the best new addition though comes in the changes to Caller ID, because that has been supercharged with Google as well. Now, any time you call a number, or receive a call from **a number that can be matched to a Google Maps business record**, Google will show you that business name, and possibly a picture (though that part of the feature has been a bit dodgy so far), instead of just the phone number. This means far fewer mystery phone numbers in your call history, and if you're like me, it means even more than that.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Also see [Android 4.4 KitKat dialer will add Google+ Caller ID and enhanced search options](http://www.mobileburn.com/22186/news/android-44-kitkat-dialer-will-add-google-caller-id-and-enhanced-search-options) for a second source, and AndroidPolice's [Google Does Caller ID: KitKat 4.4 Matches Numbers Against Google Places, And Starting In 2014, Google Personal Accounts](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/11/04/google-does-caller-id-kitkat-4-4-matches-numbers-against-google-places-and-apps-for-business-and-starting-in-2014-google-personal-accounts/) for a third.

If it's not that, you most likely have a [CallerID app](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_callerid) (pre-) installed which does the same: matching numbers of incoming calls against some online database.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I do have KitKat installed. Thank you for detailed answer! I couldn't google the answer for some reason. So it takes the name and image from Google Maps business card.